# Need a way to distinguish between ShDocVw.InternetExplorer tab objects

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, tabs, shdocvw

I'm using `ShDocVw` interop assembly to get to [`InternetExplorer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) objects.

```
foreach(InternetExplorer IE in new ShellWindowsClass())
{
   Console.Log(IE.HWND.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

The result is - all the tabs of same window report `HWND` equals `MainWindowHandle` of that window`s process. In fact, I cannot find *any* distinct information in these objects that would differentiate them from one another.

And i need to correlate these instances to real tabs in order to match them to windows events (window focus change mostly). Would be great to find a link between this object and corresponding `Frame Tab` or `TabWindowClass` window instance.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Okay, this is not perfect, but here's what i came up with:

1. Get `HWND` from [`InternetExplorer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object, this is handle of the **window**.
2. Use [`EnumChildWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`FindWindowEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to traverse its chlidren and find child windows having class `Frame Tab`. You'll get an `IntPtr tabHandle` - the handle of  the **tab**. I personally like `FindWindowEx` better here, since it will not use a callback, but iterate in a loop...
3. Then, use `FindWindowEx` again on the `tabHandle` discovered in #2 to get to a child with class `TabWindowClass`. You'll get `IntPtr tabTitleHandle` - this is the window that holds **tab window title** (which includes location name + " - internet explorer smth", i write "smth" because this text can vary, as MSIE distribution can be customized).
4. Use `GetWindowText` on `tabTitleHandle` to get the window title.
5. Now, iterate through `InternetExplorer` objects in `ShellWindowsClass` collection, first of all check PID - we only need to compare instances created by the same process, then, check if window title you got in #4 `.StartsWith(IE.LocationName + " - ")`. Note the " - ", since we can assume there will be some text identifying the browser itself, but since it can be customized - can't really guess it. If window title starts with the location name, we'll assume they corellate.

As i said, this is not perfect (since the final match is made by title), but it's the best i got so far. Hope it will help. And i am still waiting for the perfect solution, keep digging guys! ;)